A neat functional equation $f(x)=f(x+c)-f'(x+c)$
While investigating I thought of this functional equation
$$ f(x)=f(x+c)-f'(x+c) $$
and I wondered if there are any real analytic non-constant solutions. Here $c$ is some constant.

Are there any real analytic non-constant solutions?

It sort of reminds me of $f'(x)-f(x)=0$ which $f(x)=e^x$ satisfies but different. I tried integrating this equation but didn't get the solution yet.

If $c=1$ then linear functions work too.

yea you're right @Empy2 I should have written are there any real analytic nonlinear solutions

Not a solution, but setting $x \mapsto x-c$, multiplying by the integrating factor $\exp(-x)$ and changing the dependent variable to $g(x)=\exp(-x) f(x)$ gives the simpler looking delay differential equation
$g'(x)=-\exp(-c) g(x-c)$.

Then scale $x$ to $x/\exp(-c)$ and get $g\prime(x)=-g(x-d)$

This answer goes a bit beyond that of user1337 and exploits the fact that  the differential functional equation is linear. Define the quasipolynomial
$$P(s)=(1-s)e^{sc}-1$$ and observe that it has an infinite and countable number of complex zeros, which we denote by $\lambda_k$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Those zeros can be computed using the expression
$$\lambda_k=\frac{W_k\left(-c e^{-c}\right)}{c}+1$$
where $W_k$ denotes the $k$-th branch of the Lambert W function. We can then define the general solution
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \alpha_ke^{\lambda_kx}
$$
where $\alpha_k\in\mathbb{C}$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, are free parameters that can be determined using the initial condition of the problem.

As in the comments, shifting $x \mapsto x-c$, multiplying by the integrating factor $\exp(-x)$, and changing the dependent variable to $g(x)=\exp(-x) f(x)$ transforms the problem to the delay differential equation
$$g'(x)=-\exp(-c)g(x-c) $$
Assuming a solution of the form $g(x)=\exp(k x) $ gives
$$k \exp(kx)=-\exp(-c)\exp(kx-kc). $$
This has a solution
$$k=\frac{W\left(-c e^{-c}\right)}{c},$$
and translating back to the original problem, we get the nonlinear solution
$$f(x)=\exp(x) \exp \left(\frac{W\left(-c \exp(-c)\right)}{c} x \right) .$$
